# geom_line How to draw confidence interval around the mean line?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have multiple values and I would like to draw one line with a 95% confidence interval. On the x-axis I have different times of the experiment (categorical var), and on the y-axis there is a stress level (continuous var). Now I would like to have this one line that also includes the 95% conf. int. drawn around it. Would be nice to have the conf. int. area, for example, a bit transparent. Any ideas?

The code I have at the moment looks like this:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = Time, y = Stress, group=1)) +
       geom_smooth(stat = 'summary', fun.y = mean) +
       stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="line")
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `se =TRUE`should do the trick.

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = Time, y = Stress, group=1)) +
          geom_smooth(stat = 'summary', fun.y = mean, se =TRUE) +
          stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="line")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately i get the same blue line with no conf.in. I´ve also been trying with geom_line instead of geom_smooth, and tried to add some code that would add the conf.int, yet no success.

Comment: I cannot really tell why this isn't working without having access to your data... Can you post a minimum reducible example?